# Tiny deep red flower shrub species ID

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit, flowers

I found this plant with maple like leaves blooming after rains this july.I am in Bhubaneswar,India.
[image: flowers]
[image: leaves]

Answer (score 1):

It's [***Jatropha gossypiifolia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jatropha_gossypiifolia#/media/File:Bellyache_Bush_(Jatropha_gossipifolia)_in_Hyderabad,_AP_W_IMG_9473.jpg), a medium-sized (maximum 15m) shrub.The leaves are similar to the leaves of a cotton plant (*Gossypium*). Often categorized as an agricultural weed. Poisonous for mammals also. Commonly used for the production of Biodiesel.

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jatropha_gossypiifolia)-

> There are many common names for Jatropha gossypiifolia including bellyache-bush, black physicnut, and cotton-leaf physicnut in English; pinon negro, pinon colorado, and tua-tua in Spanish; medicinier noir and medicinier rouge in French; mamoninha and peao-roxo in Brazil; jarak merah and sibidigua in India.[4]

[NCBI Taxonomy ID: 454931](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Info&id=454931)